# Take repeated samples and add it to the a new dataframe: Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to take repeated samples from a data frame. I have the following code:

```py
df = pd.read_csv(filename) #Any data set would work, e.g, iris
new_df = pd.DataFrame(columns = df.columns, index = df.index) 
#not specifying the columns and index gives me an empty dataframe 
    
for i in range(20): #I want to take sample from the dataframe 20 times. 
    new_df.append(df.sample(n = 10, random_state = i), ignore_index = True)
        
        
    print(new_df) # This prints out columns with NaN values. Not sure what to do.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign the return from the append to the new_df:

```
df = pd.read_csv(filename) 
new_df = pd.DataFrame(columns = df.columns, index = df.index) 

for i in range(20): 
    new_df = new_df.append(df.sample(n = 10, random_state = i), ignore_index = True)
print(new_df)
```